# How to perform string comparison in textfile Line by Line with JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

1. I have requirement to save data to a textfile.
   2)Then consequently perform a comparison for each line in the text file.
2. If there is line of word that exist on the file report
   So far am able to read through the content and display on the console
   But I dont know how to go about making the comparison.

Example: Given I ran my code the first time and saved on the textfile

For example =My script ran the first time its Saved data{a,b,c} in fileLoc
*My intentions* When the script runs the next time if the same data "{a,b,c} existed in fileLoc.
I want to report this line(s).

I want to be able to capture these matches.

*Note* fileLoc will never change, my script just saves data every time in the same file=> "rawDeal.txt" with a time stamp, but my ask is to look for ways to perform some sort of string caparison of each lines.
***** Here is the code I have to read what was already in the file
Please any direction is greatly appreciated.

**NB==>>I am using fs.appendFile to add to the file every time I save a new data.
So ideally newly added data will be at the bottom ,but I want to check if any of the data already exist at any line above.**

```
//*****     create fs package
 fs = require('fs');
 readline = require('readline');
//const fs = require('fs');
//******     fileLoc to save info
 fileLoc ="C:/rawDeal.txt"

  //*********   ('\r\n') in input.txt as a single line break.
  require('fs').readFileSync(fileLoc , 'utf-8').split(/\r?\n/).forEach(function(line){
  console.log(line);
```

Comment: you need to open both files in one run

Answer (score 0):

<s>You just want to compare 2 files, line by line.</s> Check edit in the bottom

```
// file1.txt
apple
mangoes
orange

//file2.txt
apple
mangoes
orange

//noMatchFile.txt
apples
bananas
oranges
```

```js
// index.js
const fs = require("fs")
const { assert } = require("console") // for testing
const file1Location = "./file1.txt"
const file2Location = "./file2.txt"
const file3Location = "./noMatchFile.txt"

function CheckFiles(file1Location, file2Location) {
    const file1Lines = fs.readFileSync(file1Location, 'utf-8').split(/\r?\n/)
    const file2Lines = fs.readFileSync(file2Location, 'utf-8').split(/\r?\n/)
    // after these two readFile() functions, we have all the data we need

    for(let lineIndex in file1Lines) {
        if(file1Lines[lineIndex] !== file2Lines[lineIndex]) return false
    }
    return true
}

// Let's test ourselves
function main() {
    assert(CheckFiles(file1Location, file2Location) === true, 'expected file1 and file2 to match')
    assert(CheckFiles(file1Location, file3Location) === false, 'expected file1 and file3 not to match')
}

main()
```

Copy the solution to your machine and run it.
The `assert()`s would complain if the condition doesn't suffice

---

**Edit**:
After clarifying what you try to do in the comments, the solution is a bit different.

You have a file that records data, and each change is recorded as a new line.
Then you should split the file by lines, and compare line-by-line.
If there's any change, the function returns false:

```js
function CheckLines(file) {
    const fileLines = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8').split(/\r?\n/)
    for(let index = 0; index < fileLines.length - 1; index++){
        if(fileLines[index] !== fileLines[index+1]) return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir Tzahi, but I will be saving these data in the same fileLoc for the entire life of my test.I am just appending new line of data every time the script runs and I also want to make sure there is not an existing data.

Comment: So you want to compare an *old version* of file versus a *new version*?

Comment: Yes sir-everytime time my script runs say the first it will save information {a,b,c,d}, I have all these information captured as strings saved in each line .The second time it appends another record I want to now check if {a,b,c,d} exist if it does report it and do some kind of test validation.

Comment: I have tested your new method-still unable to print any difference on the console,I have intentionally saved up data{a,b,c} and upon resaving the same data hoping to get an alert that "{a,b,c} existed  but did not get any message. The solution do look promising-there was no error messages.

Comment: Then I just couldn't understand correctly your question. Could you edit + format your question and add there examples?